# Strongly typed MVC update action and jquery serialize problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an update action that I post to using jquery serialize()

```
public ActionResult Update([Bind(Exclude = "Id")]Person person)
{
   //Do stuff
   return Content("some result");
}
```

The problem is that jquery produces a string in the following format from my serialized elements: IsMale=on&name=joe ... etc (where IsMale is a checkbox on the website and bool in the model)

But ASP.NET MVC doesn't recognize "on" as valid bool, and then I get IsMale as false every time.

Wanted solution: either get jquery to give me true/false values when serializing or somehow make MVC understand on = true..

Any suggestions on how to do either?

Comment: Ah you're absolutely right, I'll go through my old questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried manually setting the "value" property on your checkbox input to "true"?

Also using Html.CheckboxFor correctly should give you the right setup for MVC to understand behind the scenes, even if you serialize with jquery.

Can you also add what version of MVC you're using?

Comment: Ah, yeah ofc, setting the value did the trick.Using MVC 3 btw.